# Foreach loop does not break in PHP, with Facebook-api

Tags: php, foreach, break

Iam trying to breakout a foreach loop 
after a certain number in php 
that gets my movies from Facebook.

I think that it is something small en stupid.
Here is what i got:

```
  try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_movie_info = $facebook->api('/me/movies?fields=name,genre,release_date,picture,likes');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

//print_r($user_movie_info);

$numer_of_movies_allowed = 2;
$movie_counter = 0;

foreach($user_movie_info['data'] as $movie) {

    if ($movie_counter === $number_of_movies_allowed ) {
        break;
    }

    echo '<img src="' .$movie['picture']['data']['url']. '">'; 
    echo $movie['name'];  
    echo $movie['release_date']; 
    echo $movie['genre']; 
    echo $movie['likes']; 
    echo "</br> </br>";
    $movie_counter ++;  
}

print ($movie_counter);

print ($numer_of_movies_allowed);
```

It doesn't break out after 2 movies but shows them all.

if i use:

```
if ($movie_counter == $number_of_movies_allowed )
```

or

```
if ((int)$movie_counter === (int)$number_of_movies_allowed )
```

No movies are shown at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numer_of_movies_allowed = 2;
$movie_counter = 0;

foreach($user_movie_info['data'] as $movie) {

    if ($movie_counter === $number_of_movies_allowed ) {
```

It might help if you wrote the variable name correct on initialization … `$numer_of_movies_allowed` is not the same as `$number_of_movies_allowed`.

And if you had set your error_reporting to a sensible level for developing, this whole question would have been totally unnecessary (because PHP would’ve told you that the variable inside the if condition is not set) – **SO DO IT NOW!**

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($movie_counter === $number_of_movies_allowed )
```

should be:

```
if ($movie_counter == $number_of_movies_allowed )
```

Comment: The == might give unexpected results. It's better to parse `$movie_counter` as integer (since it's what is expected anyways).

Comment: Really? `$movie_counter` is initialized to 0, then simply incremented. `$numer_of_movies_allowed` is set to an integer and never modified. There's no real reason to use `===` here unless your style is to use `===` everywhere you can (which admittedly isn't a bad idea).

Comment: if I use "==" instead of "===" no movies are visible. so it breaks out immediately i think?

Answer (score 1):

=== requires that both datatypes are equal. You must parse $movie_counter to int or remove one equal sign.

try

```
if ($movie_counter == $number_of_movies_allowed )
```

or

```
if ((int) $movie_counter === (int)$number_of_movies_allowed )
```

Comment: if i use "==" or (int) then no movies are visible. So it breaks out immediately think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table I found:

```
// "===" means that they are identical  
// "==" means that they are equal  
// "!=" means that they aren't equal.

         false   null    array()  0      "0"     0x0     "0x0"   "000"    "0000"
false    ===     ==      ==       ==      ==     ==      !=      !=       !=    
null     ==      ===     ==       ==      !=     ==      !=      !=       !=    
array()  ==      ==      ===      !=      !=     !=      !=      !=       !=    
0        ==      ==      !=       ===     ==     ===     ==      ==       ==    
"0"      ==      !=      !=       ==      ===    ==      ==      ==       ==    
0x0      ==      ==      !=       ===     ==     ===     ==      ==       ==    
"0x0"    !=      !=      !=       ==      ==     ==      ===     ==       ==    
"000"    !=      !=      !=       ==      ==     ==      ==      ===      ==    
"0000"   !=      !=      !=       ==      ==     ==      ==      ==       ===
```